# What if a cassandra node goes down

Tags: node.js, bash

I have cassandra cluster with 3 nodes based on linux. I can connect for example with cqlsh in bash script to first node and everything is ok, if this first node will be down my application have to catch it and connect to the second node etc... Is there ny possibility to connect to cluster and then cluster to be responsible to redirect me to the second node if the first one is down?
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

All Cassandra drivers come with load balancing and maintain list of active nodes. No worry, switching to live node is transparent to users.